# Warning Messages - Slow Builds

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have inherited a Visual Basic Windows Form application. I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. It is a fairly large solution with multiple projects. The build time is nearly 1 minute. I have about 8000 warning messages after the solution builds. I was wondering if the the 8000 warnings messages is impacting on the build time. I am trying to reduce the build time and happy to spend time fixing the warnings, but not sure if the build time will be reduced as a result of fixing the warning messages.

I know that it is not good practice to have any warnings at all, I do intend to fix these over time.

Thoughts?